# Finding a small description length/compression of variable length lists of rational numbers

Tags: information-theory, compression

Suppose we have data in form of variable length lists of rational numbers where the order in which the numbers are listed is arbitrary. What is the best way to represent/encode this data so that all of the data can be represented by a fixed size? It is important that we are able to reproduce the original list within some $\epsilon$ distance of the original list.

In our particular case, we have a bunch of unique, unordered (,,) coordinates representing the position of different objects in a system and would like to encode them as efficiently as possible while retaining as much of the original information as possible (possibly encoding the 's, 's, and 's in the same way, but separately). The balancing act between encoding size and information loss comes from the fact that we hope to be as stingy as possible with the amount of memory we need while also being able to retain as much of the original data as we can. We typically have a few coordinates to deal with (~10-15), but it is possible to have systems with an arbitrary number of objects in them. That said, the distribution of the number of objects in a system is heavy tailed.

One idea we are exploring is to use ideas from compressed sensing. For example, mapping the list to a fixed size "image" and hitting them with a wavelet transform to get a compressible signal and using a random projection to get a low-dimensional measurement (which we can invert via compressed sensing theory).

What would be the best way to tackle this sort of problem? Also, what are some good places to start reading about how you would go about this?

Thanks!